# Confused by d3.js's event dispatch

Tags: events, d3.js

AFAICT from the [**docs**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals#d3_dispatch) on d3.js events, all the parts of the code that *generate* or *consume* such an event must have access to the `d3.dispatch()` object on which that event were "declared" (for lack of a better word).

This means that this `d3.dispatch` object has to be globally visible, i.e. it has to be held in a global variable.  Indeed, if the scope of this variable were any narrower, both generators *and* consumers of such an event would have to live within that same scope, and this clearly defeats the purpose of event-driven programming, which is to *completely decouple* the parts of the code (i.e., the *scopes*) where events are generated from those where those events are consumed.

The scheme's dependency on a shared `dispatch` object makes no sense to me.  It would be a bit better (though, IMO, not ideal) if the value returned by `d3.dispatch()` were always the same object.  AFAICT, the following test suggests that this is not the case (the leading `>` and `<` characters denote input and output, respectively):

```
> d3.dispatch() === d3.dispatch()
< false
> d3.dispatch( 'foo' )
< d3_dispatch {foo: function, on: function}
> d3.dispatch().foo()
VM10701:2 Uncaught TypeError: d3.dispatch(...).foo is not a function(anonymous function) @ VM10701:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM10514:883InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM10514:816InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM10514:682
```

---

Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but why do they have to be global? why not closured in a factory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the code you can see that `d3.dispatch` is a factory function that returns a new `d3_dispatch` object which is a function with new `d3_dispatch_event` objects added on it, which correspond to the arguments passed into the `dispatch` factory.  The `d3_dispatch_event` factory returns an object with methods for adding and servicing and exposing listeners and their callbacks.  It also forms closures on an associative array of listeners, which will be unique for each event.

So, basically, each `dispatch` is a new object with behaviour inherited from `d3_dispatch.prototype` and `d3_dispatch_event.prototype` and state closured in the `d3_dispatch_event` factory.